# How to fix [invalid character value for cast...] with ucanaccess in microsoft access 2013

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess

**Every time i run this code it gave me error that told me there is an invalid character in the text i entered even empty text**

```
**net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::5.0.1 data exception: invalid character value for cast
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessPreparedStatement.setString(UcanaccessPreparedStatement.java:766)
    at database.data.<init>(data.java:18)
    at database.data.main(data.java:28)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: invalid character value for cast
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.setParameter(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.setString(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessPreparedStatement.setString(UcanaccessPreparedStatement.java:764)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: invalid character value for cast
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Scanner.convertToNumber(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.types.NumberType.convertToType(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more**
```

**This is Class**

```
package database;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class data {
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement stat;
    
    public data() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        
        try {
            //Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/Gobran_Group/Desktop/ /H/data.accdb");
            
            stat = con.prepareStatement("insert into records(ID,Name)values(?,?) ");
            stat.setString(1, name);
            stat.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Finish");
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        new data();
    }
}
```

**The Jars i used**

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmFO75QZK_9paZkm2e1xiAtYnvI?e=sOdrcS

Comment: Is the ID field an autonumber type? If so, probably should not include it in the INSERT statement.

Comment: @June7 when i deleted ID row from access file it gave me another error:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmFO75QZK_9pa-Ms95g6y89SjRI?e=uA8p5H

Comment: @June7 See the photo for more info about error in oneDrive url

Comment: Deploying multi-user db via OneDrive is a bad idea. What research have you done on the topic? Review https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/using-ms-access-on-onedrive/880e752f-9d66-41d9-838e-d80e45ba5a17 The link in your question doesn't work.

Comment: Ok that should work : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EqpNyYqFw16p8MwKeRettF74zl6symzH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It opens but hard to read. Code and error info should be text in question, not linked images. Sorry, I don't know UCANACCESS so can't help further.

Comment: @June7 Ok I forgot to remove ID name  from stat and its value and thanks

Comment: "i deleted ID row from access file" - why would you do that?

Comment: i removed ID name from code :

            `stat = con.prepareStatement("insert into records(ID,Name)values(?,?) ");`

and deleted ? from code to be like this :

             `stat = con.prepareStatement("insert into records(Name)values(?) ");`

and added ID row with autoNumber type again to file